# Product collection is not showing Products on frontend

Tags: php, mysql, magento2, magento2.4

**here is my block file:
path:-Vendor\Module\Block**

```
<?php 

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_productCollectionFactory ;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {    
        $this->_productCollectionFactory  = $productCollectionFactory;    
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

**here is my template file:
path:-Vendor\Module\view\frontend\templates**

```
<?php 

    $collection = $block->getProductCollection();
    print_r($collection);
?>
```

can any one help me with this part?
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$collection = $block->getProductCollection();
foreach($collection as $product){
    print_r($product->getData());
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Same No ouput in frontend it's showing blank on frontend! It is also showing error in log of getData() function!

Answer (score 0):

Try `$block->getProductCollection()->getItems()` in the template. It returns an array of products.